# MS Access query produces no values

Tags: ms-access, ms-office, vba, ms-access-2010

This code was earlier working perfectly but today it's giving me no values. Whereas the possible resultant values are already available in relevant tables. Here is the query which has problems.

```
  Private Sub BR_ID_LostFocus()   
  Dim s As String
  s = "Select Seat_No.Seat_No FROM Seat_No Where Seat_No.Seat_No <= (select    br_info.Seats_Reserved from br_info where Br_info.br_id=forms!pasenger_detail!br_id) AND (Seat_No.Seat_No) NOT IN (SELECT pasenger_detail.seat_no FROM pasenger_detail);"
  Me.Seat_No.RowSource = s
  Me.Seat_No.Requery
  End Sub
```

[image]

[image]

Comment: 1. there is no filtering in subquery  NOT IN (SELECT pasenger_detail.seat_no FROM pasenger_detail); is it ok?  2. Is form pasenger_detail opened ?  what do 'debug.print forms!pasenger_detail!br_id' print into immediate window?

Comment: your tip is right, and i have put filter there and got result, thanks.

Comment: Should i write it as answer?

Comment: yes you can write it as answer. it solved my problem which was occurred.

Comment: but few other new logical errors are came to me after applying this. i am looking at them to understand why they occur. if i dont have solution then again i will come to this forum for help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. there is no filtering in subquery NOT IN (SELECT pasenger_detail.seat_no FROM pasenger_detail); is it ok?
2. Is form pasenger_detail opened ?
3. what do 'debug.print forms!pasenger_detail!br_id' print into immediate window?

Comment: without filtering this query is giving me required data. pasenger_detail form  is opened and i entered different  data in it. while entering BR_id (bus reserved id) it is showing me no  of buses reserved but it is not showing me seat_no. seat_no depended on the selection of reserved buses. as on all reserved buses client can reserved different no of seats for his pasengers.

Comment: here is the picture of form on which i want to store data but facing problem when i want to enter data in  seat_no field